# Is WSE 3.0 Supported?

Tags: wcf, wse, wse3.0

Our client claimed, that WSE 3.0 isn't supported by Microsoft anymore. Is it true ? Where can I find more info about that ?

Comment: WSE is obsolete, and has been for years. WCF completely replaces it.

Comment: The question still stands though about whether WSE3 is supported, not whether it is obsolete.  VB6 is obsolete and completely replaced by .NET, but Microsoft still support VB6.  I too would be interested to know if Microsoft provide support for WSE3, as if they don't it adds weight to a business case for an upgrade to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Functionality of WSE was included in WCF. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732008.aspx) is information about migrating from WSE to WCF.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MS blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2012/10/25/web-service-enhancements-wse-supported-environments/), WSE 3.0 lifecycle conforms to that of .NET framework 2.0, and the support for the latter ended on July 12, 2011.